# Convert RGBA to Hex or ARGB to Hex

Tags: javascript, html, flash, color-scheme

**I am trying to convert a decimal colour code from a Flash Application into a hexadecimal colour code for HTML display**

I have these numbers which are 8 digits long, but I am not sure if they are ARGB or RGBA. Is there a way to figure this out from the colour codes themselves?

I have a javascript function that can convert a decimal to a hexadecimal number but I am not compensating for the A value(or removing it). Can you help me fix my function to extract/remove the A value from the RGB decimal code?

```
function decimalToHex( num )
{
  if (num == null || num == "undefined") { return "0xFFFFFF"; }

  var intNum = (parseInt(num,10)) & 8;  // does this remove the most significant 8 bits?
  return intNum.toString(16);
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.  Are you trying to convert dec to hex, or RGBA with a background color to RGB?

Comment: `Is there a way to figure this out from the colour codes themselves?` No; at least not in all cases.

Comment: well I'm trying to convert a flash col value(which I am unsure if its either ARGB or RGBA) to some thing like #ffffff form. So would that be decimal to hex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the alpha value is in the highest byte, then bitwise AND with 0x00FFFFFF to remove that.  So:

```
var intNum = (parseInt(num,10)) & 0x00FFFFFF;
```

Or, if the alpha value is in the lowest byte, bitwise AND with 0xFFFFFF00, then shift right 8:

```
var intNum = (parseInt(num,10) & 0xFFFFFF00) >> 8;
```